# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am building a react project I get the following error

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `Pins`. Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

cheak my Pins component inside container folder

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';
import Feed from '../components/Feed';
import Search from '../components/Search';
import CreatePin from '../components/CreatePin';
import PinDetail from '../components/PinDetail';

const Pins = ({ user }) => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

  return (
    <div className="px-2 md:px-5">
      <div className="bg-gray-50">
        <Navbar searchTerm={searchTerm} setSearchTerm={setSearchTerm} user={user && user} />
      </div>
      <div className="h-full">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Feed />} />
          <Route path="/category/:categoryId" element={<Feed />} />
          <Route path="/pin-detail/:pinId" element={<PinDetail user={user && user} />} />
          <Route path="/create-pin" element={<CreatePin user={user && user} />} />
          <Route path="/search" element={<Search searchTerm={searchTerm} setSearchTerm={setSearchTerm} />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pins;
```

Comment: Could you show where the file is being imported at? It's possible your import is wrong.

Comment: I would also validate the paths are the files you expect, maybe you imported the wrong file (I know i accidentally autocomplete the wrong import all the time)